# ASP.net MVC making cell contents as link in Grid.MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, mvcgrid

I am developing an ASP.net MVC application.

Earlier I used the following code to display a table of products.

```
foreach (var item in Model)
{
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      @Html.ActionLink(item.productName, "ViewProduct", "Showcase", 
        new { productID = item.productID }, null)
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      @item.quantity
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      @item.price
    </div>
  </div>  
}
```

It worked fine, I was able to make the Nx1'st element as a link to redirect to the view that displays the product's details.

Then I wanted to implement GridView to display products table using MVC.Grid Nuget package.

**Grid works fine but I can't make the Nx1'st element as link so that I can redirect.**

I tried out this but it's not working.

```
  @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>{
   columns.Add(model => model.productName).Titled("Name").Filterable(true)
     .RenderValueAs(o => Html.ActionLink(o.productName, "ViewProduct", "Showcase", 
       new { productID = o.productID }, null));
   columns.Add(model => model.quantity).Titled("Quantity Available");
   columns.Add(model => model.price).Titled("Price");
 }).WithPaging(3).Sortable(true)
```

The output that I get in the Nx1 cell is:

```
<a href="/Showcase/ViewProduct/?productID=15">Galaxy Note 3</a>
```

Desired output:
[Galaxy Note 3](http://google.com)

Please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: try
columns.Add(model => model.productName).Titled("Name").Filterable(true)
     .RenderValueAs(model => Html.ActionLink(model.productName, "ViewProduct", "Showcase", 
       new { productID = model.productID }, null));

Comment: Still not working I am getting the same output

Comment: can you show the output that its showing and the desired one?

Comment: I have mentioned in the question, I am getting the entire <a> with the product's name not a clickable link

Comment: Why is the question tagged kendo-grid? Are you using kendo UI?

Comment: sorry I am not using it

Answer (score 18):

This solved the problem

```
columns.Add(model => model.productName).Titled("Name")
 .Filterable(true).Sanitized(false).Encoded(false).
   RenderValueAs(model => Html.ActionLink(model.productName, 
     "ViewProduct", "Showcase", new { productID = model.productID }, null)
       .ToHtmlString());
```

Comment: great question, great answer!

Comment: Good find.  I did not need ToHtmlString, but I was missing Sanitized(false) and Encoded(false).  Adding these two methods in the chain fixed my problem.

Comment: what about XSS vulnerability :)