# Add Control column in grid MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Am trying to add link column in Grid.

**My Trying:**

**Try 1**

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
        @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
   {
       columns.Add(c => c.UserId).Titled(Resources.Resource.user_id);
       columns.Add(c => c.UserName).Titled(Resources.Resource.user_name);
       columns.Add(c => c.Mailid).Titled(Resources.Resource.mailid);
       columns.Add(c => c.Role).Titled(Resources.Resource.role);
       columns.Add(c => c.Dept).Titled(Resources.Resource.dept);
       columns.Add(c => c.Designation).Titled(Resources.Resource.designation);
       columns.Add(c => c.State).Titled(Resources.Resource.city);
       columns.Add(c => c.Country).Titled(Resources.Resource.country);
       columns.Add()
       .SetWidth(30)
       .RenderValueAs(data => new HtmlString ("<button type='submit' value=''>Download</button>" ));
   }).WithPaging(10).EmptyText("No data found")

    </div>
```

**Try 2 :**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
        @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
   {
       columns.Add(c => c.UserId).Titled(Resources.Resource.user_id);
       columns.Add(c => c.UserName).Titled(Resources.Resource.user_name);
       columns.Add(c => c.Mailid).Titled(Resources.Resource.mailid);
       columns.Add(c => c.Role).Titled(Resources.Resource.role);
       columns.Add(c => c.Dept).Titled(Resources.Resource.dept);
       columns.Add(c => c.Designation).Titled(Resources.Resource.designation);
       columns.Add(c => c.State).Titled(Resources.Resource.city);
       columns.Add(c => c.Country).Titled(Resources.Resource.country);
       columns.Add()
       .SetWidth(30)
       .RenderValueAs(data => Html.ActionLink("Edit","Edit",new {id = data.UserId }));
   }).WithPaging(10).EmptyText("No data found")

    </div>
```

Both are not working. What am doing wrong here?
Am using `VS 2017, MVC 5`

Comment: What is the html that your `RenderValueAs(..)` is generating?

Comment: its showing the html code as text in column

Comment: Refer [ASP.net MVC making cell contents as link in Grid.MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059864/asp-net-mvc-making-cell-contents-as-link-in-grid-mvc)

Comment: Try on the second attempt 
RenderValueAs(data => Html.ActionLink(" ","Edit","Edit",new {id = data.UserId }));
notice the blank " " for ActionLink argument...

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks its working.